# Fitting a bias in a weight decay regression using least-squares

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression

I'm calcualting the weights for a [linear regression with weight-decay](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat857/node/155), i.e. normally I am trying to find `beta = (X'X + lambda I)^-1 X'Y` where `X` has `n` rows of `D` features each and `Y` is a vector of outputs for each row of `X`.

I've been fitting without a bias term by using:

```
def wd_fit(A, y, lamb=0):
    n_col = A.shape[1]
    return np.linalg.lstsq(A.T.dot(A) + lamb * np.identity(n_col), A.T.dot(y))
```

I'd like to also calculate a bias or intercept term for the fit, instead of having it pass through the origin.  I'd like to keep the same call to lstsq, so if there's some matrix transform I can carry out, that would be ideal.  My inclination is to append column of 1s *somewhere*, so that `X_mod` say would then have `D+1` features where the last relates to the intercept value, but I'm not quite sure where that should be or even if it's correct.

Comment: Can you give some more information on the equation you are trying to implement? (edit your question)

Comment: @Hida I added some information, let me know if you need more. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to mean-center your variables, adding a column of ones will work and is a perfectly acceptable solution.

The bias term will just be the coefficient at the position of the added column.

Comment: Thanks.  How about if I was to mean-center the input?  Is there some other method?

Comment: If you center the data there is no need for the column of ones.